# My app keeps saying "Unfortunately, app has stopped"

Tags: android

[This is the Java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngs07.jpg)

The logcat says-

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' 
on a null object reference
```

Comment: can you add the code? If you want some help we need to see the code

Comment: update your question with your java and xml code please

Comment: Based off your code, it looks like the `findviewById` call is returning null, double check your button's id

Comment: Your variable **button3** has not assigned any reference to your xml, please assign object with variable button3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

ok..i got your java file

please update it to this

```
button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
//remove { from end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code I can see that based on some button click you are calling setContentView() again.

Hence I assume you have more buttons is in other layout file. So findViewById function for the button which is in other view will only work after setContentView for that view has been called.

So may be you can put the dependent code inside first OnClick() event where you are changing the content view.